# Julia: Function gives same output albeit inputs are changing

Tags: julia

I have some data on which I want to perform an operation, namely detrending. Since I need to it a couple of times, I wrote a function to do that. It looks like that:

```
function Detrend(input_var,detrended_var,trend_var,df,list_of_countries,StartYear)
  for i in 1:length(list_of_countries)
    country_name = list_of_countries[i]
    cond = (df[:year] .>= StartYear)&(df[:country] .== country_name)
    Y = convert(Array,df[cond,input_var],NaN)
    X = convert(Array,df[cond,:time],NaN)
    X2= convert(Array,df[cond,:time2],NaN)

    regdata = DataFrame()
    regdata[:Y] = Y
    regdata[:X] = X
    regdata[:X2] = X2

    #OLS = glm(Y ~ X, regdata, Normal(), IdentityLink())
    lm1 = fit(LinearModel, Y~ X + X2, regdata)
    df[cond,trend_var] = predict(lm1)
    df[cond,detrended_var] = df[cond,input_var]-df[cond,trend_var]
  end
end
```

I take a Dataframe, use the name of the columns to perform some operations and save my evaluation to the Dataframe.

My problem is now, whenever I call the function like that:

```
input_var = :iy
detrended_var = :iyDetrend
df[detrended_var] = DataArray(Float64, total_length)
trend_var = :iytrend
df[trend_var] = DataArray(Float64, total_length)
StartYear = 1980

Detrend(input_var,detrended_var,trend_var,df,list_of_countries, StartYear)
```

The result I get from predict(lm1) is always the same, such that trend_var is always the same, even if I change input_var (it is the correct result for the first run, but not for the rest). More strangely, if I do not call the function, but instead write what is inside the function under every change of inputs, I get the correct result. Calling the function however sticks seemingly for trend_var with the first input it gets. Does anybody know where the issue might be? Is there something wrong with how I use predict?

Many thanks,
Ilja

Comment: Can you add enough code so that someone can reproduce it on their own machines? Also it might be useful for you to print some values from each variable within the function to see what is not changing.

Comment: Strangely enough again, after I closed Atom and reopened it, I cannot reproduce that behavior. Everything works now as it should. Anyway, thank you for your help!

Comment: you have not fixed a seed for the random number generator. if you add something like `srand(2016)` at the top of your script, then do the results become reproducible?

Comment: There is nothing random in my code, so I don't see how a seed for the random number generator should change something. As I cannot reproduce that behavior and the code now works as intended in the version presented above, I would like to close this thread.